# Select tag does not work on left click but works on right click

Tags: jquery, html

I am using multiple select tags in a form. They appear like images and are not editable when left clicked but any select that is clicked becomes editable when right clicked. Now if you right click on another select, it becomes editable but the select that you just made editable appears like an image again unless right clicked.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net?

Comment: yep some html code would be nice. copy/paste your code and indent code by 4 whitespaces then it gets posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not just the selects but the input fields in the form were not editable. This is some sort of bug in firefox. You can find it on their forum. Focusing the select or input when it is clicked makes things work as expected.